# Two edit text in same line, without overlapping

Tags: android

I've 2 EditText et1 & et2.

They are both to be shown in the same line, i.e. in front of each other.
et1 is `alignedParentLeft`
et2 is `alignedParentRight`

And, for both `android:singleLine="true"`.

Issue is, if the length of one covers the length of the screen, then it overlaps the other.

How can I make sure that both are visible. 
I'm okay, if the size is more, instead of overlapping, ellipse ('...' in the end) is shown.

Answer (score 2):

give weight in edit text.
[image]

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText />
    <EditText />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the xml of et2:

```
android:toRightOf="@+id/et1"
```

This makes sure et2 will always stay on the right of et1, so they won't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found was of using `android:layout_width:0dp`.

Use this width in one of the edit text with lower priority. When the text with higher priority gets bigger then the second one, instead of overlapping gets out of the screen,

This is not 100% what I need, but worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Edittext1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Edittext2" />

</LinearLayout>
```